# Why is the product of a matrix and vector a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

Do the columns of a matrix always represent different vectors? If so, I don't understand how if I have a $3\times3$ matrix where the rows represent the dimensions and I multiply it by a $3\times1$ column vector with the same dimensions, it will give me a vector. Some sources say the result comes from the dot product of each line - is this correct? If so, $a_{12}\cdot b_{21}$ would give zero right?

Comment: What shape would you have expected for the result?  Also what do you mean by a12 and b21

Comment: I'm basically just trying to match up what I learned in physics with what I'm learning in linear algebra. I had read today here https://mathinsight.org/matrix_vector_multiplication that multiplying a matrix A and a vector x was the same as taking the dot product of x with each of the rows of A, but then I remembered that the dot product of components on different axes is zero

Answer (score 3):

$$\left(\begin{array}{c}
   a & b & c \\
   d & e & f \\
   g & h & i
\end{array}\right)
\cdot
\left( \begin{array}{c}
x \\ y \\ z
\end{array}
\right)
=
x\left( \begin{array}{c}
a \\ d \\ g
\end{array}
\right) +
y\left( \begin{array}{c}
b \\ e \\ h
\end{array}
\right) +
z\left( \begin{array}{c}
c \\ f \\ i
\end{array}
\right)
$$

and a linear combination of three vectors is a vector.

Comment: I see thanks. Its only the same as doing a dot product on the rows when you multiply a matrix of row vectors by a column vector.

Answer (score 0):

Well, on the first level your answer is "because that is how we defined things", but this is hardly a satisfying explanation.
The real reason is that matrices are just a convenient way to represent linear functions between (finite dimensional) vector spaces, i.e. functions of the form $f \colon V \to W$ (where $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces over some field $F$) such that $f(ax + y) = af(x) + f(y)$ for all $a \in F$ and all $x, y \in V$.
These linear functions, also called *homomorphisms*, are the main things we actually study in linear algebra and since they are (structure-preserving) maps between vector spaces, the "output" of such a map is a vector.
I won't go into explaining why or how matrices represent linear functions for brevity's sake, but basically we have that every linear function (relative to the base of our choosing) can be represented as a $\dim W \times \dim V$ matrix $A_f$ such that $f(x) = A_fx$.
This is the real reason we define matrices as we do: To make them convenient representations of the objects we study.

Also let me quickly say that it is an absolute shame how many linear algebra courses never touch on linear functions but rather only focus on doing matrix stuff which, in my opinion, makes the subject more technical and obstructs the students' ability to get a good intuition about it.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ are vector spaces and there is a linear transformation $f: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$. Then $f$ can be represented by a $m\times n$ matrix $M$ so that if $v\in\mathbb{R}^m$, then $f(v)$ is computed as $M\cdot v$. This is why the multiplication of a matrix with a vector is always another vector.

The action of the linear transformation organizes vectors vectors from both $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ in important ways.

The linearly independent columns of $M$ form a basis for a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ called the column space of $M$ and is denoted as $C(M)$. The column space is where all transformed vectors “live”.

The linearly independent rows of $M$ form a sub space of $\mathbb{R}^m$ called the row space of $M$ and is denoted as $R(M)$, whose orthogonal complement, $R(M)^{\perp}$, is the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$ such that for any $v\in R(M)^{\perp}$ we have $M\cdot v=0$. This is also known as the null space of $M$ or the kernel of $M$.